# iPhone set time from time stamp based on the users current time zone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to set time in my app. I got time stamp from server (which is GMT) and I need to convert that time stamp into the date, based on the users current time zone. How its possible?

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:@"1340907963"];

 NSDateFormatter *dFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

[dFormat setDateFormat:@"d.MM.yyyy"];

NSString *theDate = [dFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

This is how I converted the time stamp in to date. And I got an out put some thing like 20 June 2012 23:55. But my actual time is 18:55

Comment: please post the timestamp you recieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you received is unix time (interval since 1970) to convert it use

```
NSString * timeStamp = @"1340907963";
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp];
```

Then to convert it to string

```
NSDateFormatter *dFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[dFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"]; 
NSString *theDate = [dFormat stringFromDate:date]; 
NSLog(theDate); // 28.06.2012 21:26:03 GMT+03:00
```

Comment: Actualy am getting an out put some thing like 20 June 2012 23:55
But my actual time is 18:55

Comment: and what is the output you need?

Comment: I need to get our current time from server. But what I got is GMT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:@"1340907963"];

NSDateFormatter *dFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dFormat setDateFormat:@"d.MM.yyyy"];

NSString *theDate = [dFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: could you please explain what this does?